# Remove Custom Project Template that was Automatically Imported

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project-template

I deleted the exported zip file that was placed in my exported templates folder and of course it still shows in Visual Studio's "Add New Project" dialog. I expected that but I'm having a difficult time finding where else the template files are stored. How do I remove a custom template?

**Edit**

I've searched the following folders (and numerous others, but these are the most obvious):
`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates`
`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache`
`%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Exported Templates`
`%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates`

Not sure if it matters, but I'm also using Windows 7 for my OS.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try looking under `%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectTemplatesCache`.  This is where the unzipped cache of the template would usually be stored.  If it isn't there, try searching for a folder named ProjectTemplatesCache anywhere in your user data directory.

Comment: Awesome, that did it! I couldn't initially see the Application Data folder because access was denied (probably a security policy enforced by our admins) but of course Microsoft and it's subfolders were accessible. Deleted the cached templates and life is prettier now. Thanks!

Comment: For VS2013 on Win7: `%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectTemplatesCache`

Comment: For VS2017 users is correct path: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version_and_optional_ID>\ProjectTemplatesCache

Comment: For VS 2019 it was this folder (installation specific) `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_9daf0883\ProjectTemplatesCache`

Comment: For VS Enterprise version 15.9.16 and Windows 10 Enterprise
`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ef05b42e\ProjectTemplatesCache`

Answer (score 21):

Templates are also stored in "My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates". Under ProjectTemplates and ItemTemplates and so on depending on the language.

EDIT: i just exported a project template. The zip file was created in 2 locations:

```
 My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Exported Templates\mytemplate.zip 
 My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\mytemplate.zip
```

deleting both of these also removed the choice from the new project dialog, so I'm not sure what's happening on your machine :(

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Stephanie, I tried that folder as well and no luck. Out of curiosity, I tried rebooting in case something was stored in-memory and when creating new projects I still see the choices. Even though I deleted the zip files in my project template folder, I can STILL create new projects with those defunct templates that I want removed. Visual Studio can be sneaky at times :)

Comment: Thanks for the help anyhow. MS likes hiding things to make life more interesting I suppose.

Comment: This is also where 2012's 'Wizards' are stored.

Comment: Yes, removing from these two locations does the job.  Visual Studio then clears it from the `ProjectTemplatesCache` folder.

Answer (score 16):

My OS **Windows 8.1** and I use **Visual Studio 2013.**

Here is the path of Custom Templates;

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

For this case, my path of custom templates like;

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

Comment: Confirmed, worked for Visual Studio 2017 Community (I also deleted cach.bin from that dir too). My location was: _%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_e6‌​6e6af9\ProjectTempla‌​tesCache_

Answer (score 6):

At least for VSIX templates, the [official way using VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293638%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) simply works:

`Tools`->`Extension Manager...`->`Installed Extensions`->`Templates`->`$yourTemplate`->`[Uninstall|Disable]`

If that works for you in the first place, you don't have to mess around with different folder layouts.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone need the answer for VS 2015 and Windows 7(I know) it's %UserProfile% \Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates

Answer (score 1):

After manually searching for some of the custom profile templates(.vstemplate),I found them at the following location:

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

It appears VS2010 installs some of the templates as extesions or the authors made it that way.I hope this helps someone.

May need to run "devenv /setup" at the run command to refresh the VS2010 after you delete the templates.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness here are all the paths you have to visit to clear template leftovers in VS 2019:

First close down VS...

1. `C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\My Exported Templates`
2. `C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
3. `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxxxx`
4. `C:\Users\USER\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxxxx`
5. `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxxxx\ProjectTemplatesCache_{GUID}`

Repeat step 5 for Item templates if any.

**NOTE:** Clear zipped templates, *.bin files and subfolders containing template items.

Comment: I guess there's something else that needs to be done: after deleting everything in those folders, my custom project template keeps showing up in VS2019 (v. 16.11.4)

Answer (score 0):

If you still see the unwanted templates displayed in the `New Project...` dialog, you have to delete (for Visual Studio 2013 Community) `{program folder}\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\cache.bin` after deleting all the unwanted files as described above.  Afterwards VS will rebuild the templates listing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem for my Visual Studio Community 2017 by first deleting the template zip files in the following folders:

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates
%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates
```

Then deleting the following folder:

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_aed38a72\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

(The identifier after "15.0_" might vary)

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Visual Studio 19 on Windows 10 it was this folder:

%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio[VS_VERSION]\ProjectTemplatesCache

I deleted the template folder and voila!