# How to remove exported templates from Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: python, templates, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I have Visual Studio 2013 Express running on Windows 8.1. Also, I installed Python Tools for Visual Studio template. I have developed Python applications a few times as well as C# stuff. For Python applications, I decided to export a general game template. Since it does not look good I wanna remove it before I attempt to export a better template. I tried search everywhere but to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Custom Project Template that was Automatically Imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627354/remove-custom-project-template-that-was-automatically-imported)

Answer (score 0):

@GeoCoder, Pavel's link is mostly what you need.  If after deleting all those files you still see it, then you need to delete `{program folder}\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\cache.bin` also.